# Programming has a home in Enterprise Networking

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions, site-scope, site-content

This stack exchange is not true to the nature of the next generation of network engineers. There are new questions in enterprise networking with regards to automation, orchestration, buzzword and we should be able to discuss them here.

I have posted this because I have noticed people do not like programming in this exchange.

Comment: "_we should be able to discuss them here._" SE sites are explicitly _not_ discussion forums. We have [chat] (you have enough reputation for that) where you can discuss and ask off-topic questions. In any case, programming questions, including networking, are covered by [so], where there are many network-savvy programmers. SE wants all programming questions to be asked on [so].